# Binding data in href attibute - VueJS

Tags: vue.js, data-binding, href

I have problem with binding data in VueJS. In code below, `user.name` is working but `user.id` in `href` attribute is not.

```
<ul id="message-user-list">
  <li v-for="user in users">
    <a href="chat.php?user={{ user.id }}">{{ user.name }}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I also tried this but it doesn't work:

```
<ul id="message-user-list">
  <li v-for="user in users">
    <a v-bind:href="chat.php?user={{ user.id }}">{{ user.name }}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

What do I do wrong? Help please.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try it like this `<a :href="'chat.php?user=' + user.id">{{ user.name }}</a>`

If you do `v-bind:` - **vue** takes everything in quotes for **js**

Comment: It works. But I have another question. What if I have PHP code there and I can't use apostrophe?

Comment: Give an example please